# remove duplicate column values inside a group

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, treeset

i have created an string[] array of row values of a csv file and stored it in array list. i need to group it based on arr[0] and delete any duplicate array values in that group.

*there can be n number columns each time. I have taken 3 columns for example*

```
List<String[]> rowList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
BufferedReader reader = null;
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\test.csv"));

String[] currLineSplitted;
while (reader.ready()) {
   currLineSplitted = reader.readLine().split(",");
   rowList.add(currLineSplitted);
}

Set<String[]> s = new TreeSet<String[]>(new Comparator<String[]>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
        int cmp = 0;
        if((o1[0]).compareTo(o2[0])==1){
            for(int i=1;i<currLineSplitted.length;i++){
            cmp = (o1[i]).compareTo(o2[i]);
            }
        } else {
            cmp=0;
        }

        return cmp;
    }
});

s.addAll(rowList);

List<Object> res = Arrays.asList(s.toArray());
for(Object obj:res){
    String[] arr = (String[])obj;
    System.out.println(arr[0]+","+arr[1]+","+arr[2]);
}
```

input file:

```
{"1","a","gh"}        
{"1","a","rs"}        
{"1","b","cd"}
{"2","a","xy"}
{"2","b","xy"}
{"3","a","pq"}
```

output:

```
1,a,gh
2,b,xy
```

Required output:

```
1,a,gh
1,a,rs //should be deleted as in group 1 a is repeated
1,b,cd
2,a,xy
2,b,xy //should be deleted as in group 2 xy is repeated
3,a,pq
```

Comment: You can create a POJO holding a row and implement a comparator. Later add those fields to a set instead of array list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost right. I modified your compare function a little. So replace your compare function with this

```
       @Override
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
            int cmp = 0;

            if(o1[0].equals(o2[0])){//grouping 1st column
                for(int i=1;i<o1.length;i++){
                    cmp = (o1[i]).compareTo(o2[i]);
                    if(cmp==0)
                        return cmp;// if two column matched return immediately
                }
            } else {
                return o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);
            }

            return cmp;
        }
```

**Remember** there is no guarantee that *String.compare* will return 1. It compares two strings lexicographically and returns zero if two strings matches. 
So in your code following line is creating a logical error.

```
o1[0]).compareTo(o2[0])==1
```

Read more about string comparator [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

create a class for example `ArrayClass`

```
public class ArrayClass{

private String firstItem,secondItem,thirdItem;

  public ArrayClass(String[] param){
    firstItem = param[0];
    secondItem = param[1];
    thirdItem = param[2];
  }

//getters and setters
}
```

then override the `equals` and `hashCode` method

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (this == obj) return true;

    if (obj == null || (this.getClass() != obj.getClass())) {
        return false;
    }

    ArrayClass aC = (ArrayClass) obj;

    return (this.firstItem.equals(aC.getFirstItem())
            && this.secondItem.equals(aC.getSecondItem()))
            || (this.firstItem.equals(aC.getFirstItem())
            && this.thirdItem.equals(aC.getThirdItem()));
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // up to you how you compute your hashcode to be unique
    return thirdItem != null ? thirdItem.hashCode() : 0;
}
```

then in your main class use `Set` instead of `List`

```
Set<ArrayClass> testSet = new HashSet<ArrayClass>();
```

then modify your `while loop`

```
while (reader.ready()) {
                ArrayClass aC = new ArrayClass(reader.readLine().split(","));
                testSet.add(aC);
            }
```

to show the output

```
for(ArrayClass aC : testSet){
            System.out.println(aC.getFirstItem()+" "+aC.getSecondItem()+" "+aC.getThirdItem());
        }
```

output:

```
1,a,gh
1,b,cd
2,a,xy
3,a,pq
```

Comment: On your code hashCode and equals are not proper each others. hashCode should consider firstItem & secondItem values.

Comment: that's is why i put a comment `// up to you how you compute your hashcode to be unique` @ErdinçTaşkın

Comment: thanks for the code. my actual goal is to get a generic solution. the number of columns is not same everytime. it can be 'n' number of columns each time.

Comment: i think this would be your best bet, you could just modify your POJO(ArrayClass) or else you would do the if-else in for loop to check every index of the array